# Alsamixer finding "item" by command line?

Tags: command-line, sound, alsa

I have 3 playback devices: 
**TV (HDMI), Headphones, Speakers**

TV uses the GPU soundcard through HDMI, Headphone and Speakers use integrated Mainboard sound.

In the following alsamixer screenshot, you can see my speakers being "Headphone" and my actual headphones being "Headphone 1" right beside it.

[image]
I would like to be able to toggle volume for both individually (by commandline possibly) so I can use only speakers or only headphones when I want to.

**I can't seem to find the corresponding entry** those two are mapped to. Amixer does not help either, how does this work overall?

By the way, when I mute "Headphone" it automatically mutes the master too, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Thanks a ton.

**Edit:**

`amixer scontrols
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',3
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',4
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',5`

```
    amixer -c 1 scontrols
Simple mixer control 'Master',0                                                                                                             
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0                                                                                                            
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',1
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
Simple mixer control 'Line',0
Simple mixer control 'Line Boost',0
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
Simple mixer control 'Capture',1
Simple mixer control 'Dock Mic',0
Simple mixer control 'Dock Mic Boost',0
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',0
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',1
Simple mixer control 'Loopback Mixing',0
```

I can change the volume now by using

```
    amixer -c 1 controls
numid=27,iface=CARD,name='Dock Headphone Surround Jack'
numid=23,iface=CARD,name='Dock Mic Jack'
numid=26,iface=CARD,name='Headphone Front Jack'
numid=25,iface=CARD,name='Line Jack'
numid=24,iface=CARD,name='Mic Jack'
numid=22,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'
numid=21,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Switch'
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Switch',index=1
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Volume'
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Volume',index=1
numid=31,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
numid=20,iface=MIXER,name='Line Boost Volume'
numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Switch'
numid=10,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Volume'
numid=19,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Boost Volume'
numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Playback Switch'
numid=8,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Playback Volume'
numid=15,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'
numid=17,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch',index=1
numid=14,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume'
numid=16,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume',index=1
numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='Loopback Mixing'
numid=18,iface=MIXER,name='Dock Mic Boost Volume'
numid=7,iface=MIXER,name='Dock Mic Playback Switch'
numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='Dock Mic Playback Volume'
numid=12,iface=MIXER,name='Input Source'
numid=13,iface=MIXER,name='Input Source',index=1
numid=29,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map'
numid=28,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map'
numid=30,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map',device=2
```

to find the numid=3 of my device. Here the actual id is **indeed** *numid=3* so to change the volume I use:

```
amixer -c 1 cset 'numid=3' 20
```

to change the volume "value" to 20. Here in my case, the db max is 64, so it sets it to 20 out of 64 (not sure the percentage). Alsamixer GUI shows some different (scaled?) values. Now I just need to figure out how to use the + and - commands, as they don't seem to work for me. Thanks so far!

Comment: This is pretty much a direct interface to the hardware, so you won't be able to change its behaviour. Anyway, please show the output of `amixer scontrols`.

Comment: I inserted the output into the original post. I thought it would be possible as I can do it through the alsamixer interfact, possibly imitate its controls?

Afaik, amixer is different to alsamixer right? Wouldn't its outputs differ from alsamixer naturally?

Comment: This looks like the GPU. Please try `amixer -c 1 scontrols`.

Comment: @CL. sorry for the late response, you can find the results in the post. It indeed found my Headphones, but I'm not sure how to proceed from now on.

Comment: For the most part, your journey has taken you through this tutorial: https://www.maketecheasier.com/alsa-utilities-manage-linux-audio-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

How to change mixer controls is described in the [`amixer` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/amixer).

You can change a simple mixer control to a percentage value, or to a dB value:

```
amixer -c1 set 'Headphone',1 50%
amixer -c1 set 'Headphone',1 -20dB
```

You can append `+` or `-` for a relative change:

```
amixer -c1 set 'Headphone',1 10%+
amixer -c1 set 'Headphone',1 10dB-
```

For the switches below, you can use `mute`/`unmute`/`toggle`.